# Python module not found because import statement is in other file than the one being executed

Tags: python

In the following structure:

```
src:
    model:
        - boardmodel.py
        - tests.py
        exceptions:
            - exceptions.py
    - visual.py
```

I'm running `visual.py` from the terminal. In my **boardmodel.py**, I have the following import:

```
from exceptions.exceptions import ZeroError, OverlapError, ArgumentError, ProximityError
```

This line causes an error when running `visual.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visual.py", line 3, in <module>
    from model.boardModel import Board
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/pythonfun/BouncingBalls/balls/src/model/boardModel.py", line 5, in <module>
    from exceptions.exceptions import ZeroError, OverlapError, ArgumentError, ProximityError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

What is the correct way to solve this problem? Should I change the import statement inside `boardmodel.py` to `from model.exceptions.exceptions import ZeroError....`? That doesn't feel like a sustainable solution, because what if I want to use `boardmodel.py` in another context? Let me her your thoughts.

EDIT:

I changed the structure to:

```
src:
    model:
        - __init__.py
        - boardmodel.py
        - tests.py
        exceptions:
            - __init__.py
            - exceptions.py
    - visual.py
```

But still I get the same error.

Comment: You could use relative imports, or adding _model_ folder to _PYTHONPATH_ env var (or to `sys.path` from code).

Comment: The complete problem would have been clearer if you showed the first few lines (including the `import` statements) from `visual.py` and `boardmodel.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place an empty file called `__init__.py` in each of the subdirectories to make them packages.

See [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) for more details

Then, within `boardmodel.py` you need to either use relative imports

```
from .exceptions.exceptions import ...
```

or absolute ones (from the root of PYTHONPATH)

```
from model.exceptions.exceptions import ...
```

When you execute a script from the command line, the directory containing the script is automatically added to your `PYTHONPATH`, and becomes the root for `import` statements

Comment: You also need to use relative imports, as Laurent says. But you did need the `__init__.py` files for them to work

Answer (score 1):

You are not at the root of your package so you need relative import.

Add a dot before `exceptions`:

```
from .exceptions.exceptions import ZeroError, OverlapError, ArgumentError, ProximityError
```

One dot mean "from the current directory"…